# Windows Task Manager Columns - Handles

Tags: memory-management, pointers, windows-xp

What is the Windows Task Manager "Handles" column a measure of?  File Handles?  Or Page File Pointers?  Also is it bad for one program to have 8000 handles?

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to Superuser rather than closed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a measure of kernel handles.  Kernel handles types and the functions that create them include:

- File handles (CreateFile)
- Memory mapped files (CreateFileMapping)
- Events (CreateEvent)
- Mutexes (CreateMutex)
- Semaphores (CreateSemaphore)
- Processes (CreateProcess)
- Threads (CreateThread)

And more than I forget or have never heard of.

8000 for a single process seems incredibly excessive.

Answer (score 1):

8000 for a single process does seem rather a lot, but not necessarily out of the question - it depends on the behaviour. You should think of handles as a special kind of memory - high usage is a possible warning sign, but not if it is stable. If the handle usage is stable, then it is not a sign of a leak, although you might have some optimisation to perform to get it to use fewer handles.